# Http2: stream closed occurring again and again

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, go-gin

While rendering JSON response from API I am getting "http2: stream closed" error many times while loading that API

I didn't used streaming I am just serving json response using **[c.JSON()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.JSON)** function of go-gin

**Packages used**

- go-gin
- go-gorm